# Is there any TTL (Time To Live ) for Documents in Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any TTL option on documents for Firebase Database . Where documents get auto deleted after that amount time.

Answer (score 1):

No such thing exists as a feature of Realtime Database or Firestore.

You can instead write your own code to periodically search for expired documents or nodes in a collection and delete them.

Comment: Okay, that helps. Thanks @Doug